# Not required field show field required when save

Tags: powerapps

[image]

Dear all,

I would like to use data card in PowerApps to save data on my premise SQL Server.

In the picture left hand side, this app created when SQL server table status field is allow null.

In the picture right hand side, this app create when SQL server table status field is not allow null.

My problem is can I create app on SQL server with table status field in not allow null and not prompt error like the picture right hand side (I also set STATUS data card property required = false).

Thank you for your help and reply.

Regards,

Tommy

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,
If your sql database has property **Not Allow Null**  then it is not possible to send null data from PowerApps. Reason been Powerpass reads configuration data from your sql database and in your database it is mentioned to make that field as **Not Allow Null**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It means that field in table at MS SQL server must set allow null if I want to let SQL Server set default value (such as field for keep record creation date. We no need to get involved user to punch  data.) Thank you.